# How to set displayName in class based component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

I'm trying to set the `displayName` property of this class that extends `React.Component`. The [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#displayname) say that `displayName` is a property, so it possible to set it in the constructor? Here's what I'm trying:

```
class TestUI extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
     this.displayName = 'CustomTestUI'
   }
}
```

But the library I'm using ([pacomo](https://github.com/unicorn-standard/react-pacomo)) isn't picking it up. Am I setting it incorrectly? I've also tried setting it outside the class like stateless components MyClass.displayName = 'Test' which also doesn't have an effect.

Edit: The answer is: `static displayName = 'CustomTestUI'`

Comment: have you tried `static displayName = 'yourName'`?

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comments, `displayName` should be set on the class as a static variable and **not** an instance using `this`.

```
class TestUI extends React.Component {
   static displayName = 'CustomTestUI';
   ...
}
```

Here are a couple of examples of where React retrieves `displayName` from the component class in [this error](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/aeda7b745d9c080150704feb20ea576238a1b9a1/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactChildFiber.js#L1312) and [this function](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/da5c87bdfa287b8493b6e40a02acbe9896fd554a/packages/react-dom/src/server/ReactPartialRenderer.js#L147).

You can also set the `displayName` of a component via `Component.displayName = 'myName'`.

```
class TestUI extends React.Component {
    ...
}

TestUI.displayName = 'CustomTestUI';
```

Answer (score 1):

The comments and answers given should suffice, however I thought it a good opportunity to describe why your initial attempt did not work (and why it would have been a bad idea anyways).

When working with classes, you have the class "constructor" which is used to create many class "instances". Inside your class methods, all references to `this` refer to the class instance. You can always access the constructor by doing `this.constructor`.

So the following would have worked, though it is very bad practice for an instance to change a property on its constructor - DO NOT DO THIS:

```
class TestUI extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
     // DO NOT DO THIS (for educational purposes only - see other answers)
     this.constructor.displayName = 'CustomTestUI'
   }
}
```